# How does Seam store conversation state in the client browser?

Tags: seam, seam-conversation

Seam's documentation says that conversational state - see [link](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/seam/Seam_Reference_Guide/Seam_contexts-Conversation_context.html) last line - can be configured to be stored in the client browser as opposed to the servlet session.  Can anyone tell me:

1. How is this configuration set?
2. How does Seam actually internally store the conversational state in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan Allen, Author of Seam in Action book and red hat Seam core developer, states

Since conversations **are stored in the session**, two requirements must be met:

- Conversation-scoped components must implement java.io.Serializable.
- The session timeout, defined in web.xml, must exceed all conversation timeouts.

As far as i know is that The *JSF Tree* **can be stored in The client side**, enabled through web.xml context param

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But keep in mind bandwidth issues when using this kind of configuration

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have read correctly? Could you point to the documentation that states that?

The only way I can see that seam can store anything on the client is through cookies. But Seam does not use anything else other than the user session, which you will get if you authenticate. (Also known as jsession id)

Comment: Sure, take a look at this link:

http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/seam/Seam_Reference_Guide/Seam_contexts-Conversation_context.html

It is last line on the page.

Comment: @smayers81: Probably an error. I wouldn't give it much thought if I where you.